# Derivative of Quadratic Form as a Linear Approximation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to find the derivative of the $quadratic$ form, for a $symmetric$ $n$ by $n$ matrix A and $ x \in \mathbb{R}^n $, $$ f(x) = x^tAx $$ such that the derivative is a linear map from $ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $. From applying the chain rule, I was able to calculate the derivative as $ f'(x) = 2x^tA $ by expanding the matrix and using the chain rule (you end up with $ f'(x) = x^t(A^t + A) = 2x^tA $, but this clearly isn't a map from $ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $, though it does appear to be the gradient of the function. Some help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, or rather it induces one. Specifically, it induces the map $y \mapsto 2 x^t A y$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Hilbert space, we have the Riesz representation theorem, so this linear functional is in fact just the inner product between a vector (which we call the gradient) and the perturbation.

Comment: Yeah, the way that the problem was set up was confusing - it stated that $ f'(x) $ was a map from $ \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $, which I interpreted as $ f' : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $ which is not the case. Thanks for the clarification though!

Comment: We unfortunately abuse notation with functions. We often write "$f(x)$" when we mean "$f$, a one-argument function whose argument we are calling $x$". But it should really mean "$f$ evaluated at $x$". It appears that your source was avoiding this pitfall, by describing $f'(x)$ as itself being a function, specifically the linearization of $f$ at the point $x$.

Comment: Definitely, and it seems like in differential geometry, it's (apparently, from my limited experience) necessary to respect convention, or else maps (differentials, especially) get confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$x(0)=x_0,\ x'(0)=v$$

So $$f(x(t))= x(t)^T A x(t) $$ so that $$ Df : {\bf R}^n\times {\bf R}^n\rightarrow {\bf R}$$ Taking the derivative: $$ Df (x_0,v) =\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} f(x(t))=v^T A x_0+x_0^T A v $$ Since $A$ is symmetric $$ x_0^T A v =(x_0^T A v)^T=v^TAx_0$$

Hence $$ Df (v)=2v^TAx_0$$

That is $Df(x_0)$ is a linear map $ Df(x_0)=2x_0^TA : {\bf R}^n\rightarrow {\bf R},\ v\mapsto 2x_0^TA v$

Comment: Thanks Hee, but in the second step, how does $f(t) = f(x(t))$? $f(t) = t^tAt$, right? Do you mean $f(x) = f(x(t))$?

Comment: Domain of $f$ is ${\bf R}^n$. When we consider a derivative of $f$, we first consider a $curve$ in a domain ${\bf R}^n$. If $x: t\in {\bf R}\rightarrow {\bf R}^n,\ x(0)=x_0,\ x'(0)=v$, then $f(x)=f(x(t))$ and $\frac{d}{dt} f(x(t))=Df (x'(0))=Df(v)$